# installing windows 7 from emergency disk, connecting with the internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, installation, drivers, ethernet

I have just reinstalled windows 7 on a laptop using an old emergency cd. Now this cd does not contain any drivers and as such it can no longer connect to the internet. This is on an dell inspiron 15 5000 series. I have tried to install the [intel ethernet drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=18713) but when trying to install the Inter(R) Network connections SNMP Agent is gives me a " microsoft snmp service is not installed" error. Not installing this instead give me a " cannot install drivers. No intel(R) adapters are present in this computer" [realtech drivers](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds019105) these gave no error but the device still shows no installed driver. BTW I'm trying to install these drivers by first downloading them via ubuntu and then move the .exes onto windows.

Does anybody know how to get these drivers?

Comment: Your downloading them from the Dell website correct?

Comment: I downloaded the drivers from the links I posted

Comment: So the answer to my question, did you download the device drivers for your laptop from Dell, would be **NO**.  I suggest you try that instead of downloading drivers for entirely different hardware.

Comment: So where would I get the dell drivers? I found this list: http://www.nodevice.com/driver/company/Dell/Network.html however it seems to hold no connection to the specs of an inspiron 15. How do I find out which driver to use? (this is really much easier on linux)

Comment: The Dell website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Head to Dell's site, and get the drivers for your version of Windows, for your laptop model.

IE: http://www.dell.com/support/home/ie/en/iedhs1/product-support/product/inspiron-15-5547-laptop/drivers